# Remarks about inhibited inlining with ICC 16.0

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, icc

I'm currently porting a lot of C++ projects from ICC (Intel C++...) 13.0 to ICC 16.0 and these 'remarks' appeared:

*remark #11074: inlining inhibited by limit max-size*

*remark #11074: inlining inhibited by limit max-total-size*

What I want to know is whether the inlining was done when using 13.0 and is inhibited now or we were just not warned with the previous version?. The answer, if someone has it, will tell me if I have to disable the warning/remark or I have to fix the limitation imposed by the new compiler in order to preserve the executable characteristics.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't *know*. But if I were to guess I'd say that the compiler probably never inlined in those cases and you are just only being told now. But, the way to know for sure is to inspect the generated asm from the old compiler and the new and compare. Not that hard :)